# Solidity function returning true in remix but false in web3 function call

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js, remix

I have this Solidity function, it is returning the right answer when called in remix IDE but in web3 call, it is returning false always

```
function checkSubscribed() public view returns(bool){
        if(block.timestamp>subscriptionPeriod[msg.sender]){
            return false;
        }
        else{
             return true;
        }
     
    }
```

My web3 call function(version 1.2.9)

```
myContract.methods.checkSubscribed().call({from:userAccount},(err,status)=>{
   console.log(status);

});
```

Deployed on kovan testnet

Answer (score 0):

Check `subscriptionPeriod[msg.sender]` and `block.timestamp`.

If you don’t know where to look at the `timestamp` value, just add a debug method to the contract:

```
function timestamp() external view returns (uint256) {
  return block.timestamp;
}
```