# Smart Contract Function in Remix returns true but in VS code returns false

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, blockchain, smartcontracts

When I compile and call the `check_If_Address_Already_Signed()`and `check_Database_Verified_Address()`function in Remix both of them return true . Now when in my Js file where I want to do some computation only if this two smart contract functions return true, when I create an instance of the smart contract and call the two functions, the `check_Database_Verified_Address()`returns false instead of true. I do not understand why ?
I will provide my smart contract code, my compile.js, as well as my Js file to do some computation (Signataire.js)
Solidity Smart Contract :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "./DataBase_Add_Verifies.sol";

// import "./Identification_C_EA.sol";

// Deno was installed successfully to /Users/pierre/.deno/bin/deno
// Manually add the directory to your $HOME/.zshrc (or similar)
//   export DENO_INSTALL="/Users/pierre/.deno"
//   export PATH="$DENO_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
// Run '/Users/pierre/.deno/bin/deno --help' to get starte
contract Signataire is DataBaseAddresses {
    mapping(address => bool) already_Signed_Addresses;

    // Event pour dire que le signataire peut signer le Jeton

    // Function pour check avec Database addresse verifie
    function check_Database_Verified_Address() public view returns (bool) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < verified_Addresses.length; i++) {
            if (verified_Addresses[i] == msg.sender) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Function pour check si Addresse a deja signe un jeton
    function check_If_Address_Already_Signed() public view returns (bool) {
        if (already_Signed_Addresses[msg.sender] == false) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Function qui ajout msg.sender a l'aray
    function Ajout_Add_Array() internal {
        if (
            check_Database_Verified_Address() &&
            check_If_Address_Already_Signed() == true
        ) {
            already_Signed_Addresses[msg.sender] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my compilation file :

```js
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const solc = require("solc");
const Web3 = require("web3");
// Loading the contract ABI and Bytecode
// (the results of a previous compilation step)
const ethers = require("ethers");

const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const sourceFolderPath = path.resolve(
  __dirname,
  "/Users/pierre/Authentification_TM/Smart-Contracts"
);
const buildFolderPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");
const getContractSource = (contractFileName) => {
  const contractPath = path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    "Signataire.sol",
    contractFileName
  );
  return fs.readFileSync(contractPath, "utf8");
};

let sources = {};

var walk = function (dir) {
  var results = [];
  var list = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  list.forEach(function (file) {
    file = dir + "/" + file;
    var stat = fs.statSync(file);
    if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
      results = results.concat(walk(file));
    } else {
      if (file.substr(file.length - 4, file.length) === ".sol") {
        sources = {
          ...sources,
          [file]: {
            content: getContractSource(file),
          },
        };
      }
      results.push(file);
    }
  });
  return results;
};
walk(sourceFolderPath);

const input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources,
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      "*": {
        "*": ["*"],
      },
    },
  },
};

console.log("\nCompiling contracts...");
const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
console.log("Done");

let shouldBuild = true;

if (output.errors) {
  console.error(output.errors);
  // throw '\nError in compilation please check the contract\n';
  for (error of output.errors) {
    if (error.severity === "error") {
      shouldBuild = false;
      throw "Error found";
      break;
    }
  }
}

if (shouldBuild) {
  console.log("\nBuilding please wait...");

  fs.removeSync(buildFolderPath);
  fs.ensureDirSync(buildFolderPath);

  for (let contractFile in output.contracts) {
    for (let key in output.contracts[contractFile]) {
      fs.outputJsonSync(
        path.resolve(buildFolderPath, `${key}.json`),
        {
          abi: output.contracts[contractFile][key]["abi"],
          bytecode:
            output.contracts[contractFile][key]["evm"]["bytecode"]["object"],
        },
        {
          spaces: 2,
          EOL: "\n",
        }
      );
    }
  }
  console.log("Build finished successfully!\n");
} else {
  console.log("\nBuild failed\n");
}
```

And here is my Signataire.js file :

```js
/*
Le signataire ne doit signer le message transmis que si les deux 
already_Signed_Addresses() et check_If_Address_Already_Signed()
sont vrais. 
Import le smart contract, call les deux fonctions, si elles sont just => ecrire code pour signer avec 
la private key d une addresse (Signgataire), si c est faux alors revert 
Ecrire une transaction du signataire au Citoyen (msg.sender), Avec comme data son Jeton signé
*/
const crypto = require("crypto");
const ethers = require("ethers");
const web3 = require("web3");
require("dotenv").config();
const { abi, bytecode } = require("./build/Signataire.json");

function getRandomJeton(Choix_Vote, N_V) {
  // Avoir deux nombre completement aleatoire
  let randomAnonymeNumber1 = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0];
  let randomAnonymeNumber2 = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0];
  // Avoir un nombre unique a chaque citoyen
  let uniqueNumber = "12345678910";
  // Mettre ensemble le nombre aleatoire et unique pour cree un nombre 100% aleatoire et unique
  let uniqueRandomValue = `${uniqueNumber}${randomAnonymeNumber2}${randomAnonymeNumber1}`;
  // Mettre ensemble les donne necessaire pour avoir le jeton
  let unhashedJeton = `${Choix_Vote}${uniqueRandomValue}${N_V}`;
  const Jeton = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(unhashedJeton).digest("hex");
  return Jeton;
}
const Jeton = getRandomJeton(1, 2);
console.log(Jeton);

//Function pour aveugle le jeton

const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(
  `wss://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_PRIVATE_KEY}`
);
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const ABI = abi;
// console.log(ABI);
const contractAddress = "0xF0168BC0DBb989bf3163f2353DdA4D3A09b073fa";
// Replace with your contract's ABI
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ABI, provider);
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
// console.log(wallet);

async function sign_jeton() {
  try {
    console.log(await contract.get_Array());
    const databaseVerified = await contract.check_Database_Verified_Address();
    const addressAlreadySigned =
      await contract.check_If_Address_Already_Signed();
    console.log(databaseVerified);
    console.log(addressAlreadySigned);
    if (addressAlreadySigned && databaseVerified == true) {
      // If both conditions are met, sign the Jeton
      const signature_Jeton = web3.eth.accounts.sign(Jeton, PRIVATE_KEY);
      console.log("Signature:", signature_Jeton);
      process.exit();
    } else {
      console.log("Conditions not met. Cannot sign Jeton.");
      process.exit();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    process.exit();
  }
}
sign_jeton();
// process.exit();
```

I have seen that when I try to `console.log(verfied_Adresses)` from the contract in my JS file I get `0x000...` so the js file can not read the array from the Smart contract and so it cannot return true on the `check_Database_Verified_Address()` because `0x000...` doesnt match `msg.sender` . It is not a problwm with the import of this array because i tried to declared it in the same smart contract, and it still didnt work, I also tried to declare it in a contructor functions, didnt work. I tried to declare a different array like uint8 myArray[] = [1,2,3] and I replaced the verified_Adresses with the myArray conserving the exact same logic, and it did work. So I do not understand where the problem comes from, is it the address array that cannot be accesed  outside of the contract ? Also I saw another person asking the same kind of question with a function aboutthe timstamp of the block, but it didnt help, here is the link of the question : [Solidity function returning true in remix but false in web3 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62746130/solidity-function-returning-true-in-remix-but-false-in-web3-function-call)
Any help would higlhy be appriciated ,

Thank you very much for taking your time :)

Comment: After reading documentations I have found the issue. For anyone having the same problem, you need to replace msg.sender in the solidity code by a variable . that means instead of having msg.sender we declare address user = msg.sender , normally it will work. Thank you

Comment: If you have found the solution, then it would be better to answer to your own question :-)

Answer (score 1):

After reading documentations I have found the issue. For anyone having the same problem, you need to replace msg.sender in the solidity code by a variable . that means instead of having msg.sender we declare address user = msg.sender , normally it will work. Thank you